# make highchart stacked column chart count zero value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highchart stacked column chart that shows the positive, zero and negative return for the various sectors. But I am facing a strange problem, because I have three series, if i have series value counted less than 3 the chart shows wrong information i am not what could be the reason. for example, in my code please note the jute, paper & printing and telecom sector value; the sum of these values are less than 3 but they have 3 values for each and the chart shows wrong info. if you put your cursor you will notice that and also you will see the stacked are also wrong.  fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Snowbell92/KtrZz/ . check the last sector "telecom". it has a positive value of 2, but when I turn of the positive value from the legend, telecom still gets a column for two, just colored red. the value isn't getting updated at all. my javascript for highchart below:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            height: 400
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Todays Sector Up/Down Ratio' 
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Bank', 'Engineering', 'Food & Allied', 'Fuel & Power', 'Jute','Textile','Pharmaceuticals','Paper & Printing','Serv. & R. Estate', 'Cement','Miscellaneous','Insurance','NBFI','IT Sector','Travel & Leisure','Ceramics','Mutual Funds','Tannery','Telecom'],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }

        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            labels:
        {
        enabled: false
    },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
        style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 20,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
             series: {
            minPointLength:15,
            borderColor: '#f2f2f2',
            borderWidth: 2,
            shadow: true
        },
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                 pointPadding: 0.1,
                 dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    verticalAlign: 'top'

                }

            }

        },
        credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
        series: [{
            name: 'Positive Return',
            data: [15, 20, 14, 7, 1, 20,15,1,2,5,4,20,15,2,2,3,35,2,2],
            color: '#008000',
        }, {
            name: '0 Return',
            data: [5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 9,8,0,1,1,3,5,5,2,0,1,5,3,0],
            color: '#1F497D',
        }, {
            name: 'Negetive Return',
            data: [10, 5, 1 , 5, 1, 3,2,0,1,1,2,21,3,2,1,1,3,0,0],
            color: '#F40909',
        }]
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking why your chart is showing column even the value is zero, it's because of the [`minPointLeght`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.minPointLength) setting in `plotOptions`:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        minPointLength:15,  //get rid of the minPointLength setting and you will be fine
        borderColor: '#f2f2f2',
        borderWidth: 2,
        shadow: true
    },
```

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KtrZz/1/